# Git repo issue: failed to unpack tree object HEAD

Tags: linux, git, android

I am facing one issue with one of my Android project while initializing repo sync with error like

> fatal: failed to unpack tree object HEAD" for one particular project along with error.GitError: cannot initialize work tree for /project.

So I request you to help me getting out of this error.

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered a similar problem, but not for `HEAD`:

```
fatal: failed to unpack tree object 27897029c61a19819a55923c664da5796cc82d1d
error: Submodule 'submoduleXYZ' could not be updated.
error: Cannot update submodule: submoduleXYZ
```

Updating the submodule didn't help. I resorted to `git reset --hard origin/theBranchName`, then `git checkout theBranchName`, and `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently, it was due to changing of `url` field in .gitmodules inside a submodule.

So what I guess was happening, the git was trying to find a new commit hash of submodule-submodule, but since under the url there was no such hash, it gave the error.

I tried to use `git submodule sync` in different ways, but nothing worked.

So unfortunately for now, I know only one solution to this: remove the whole repository and clone again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to not pushed submodules.

`git reset --hard --recurse-submodules` tried to reset to committed submodule sha.

The submodule itself was not pushed so that sha was not pulled.

After I pushed these submodules from development workspace and then pulled into the problem having workspace, the command `git reset --hard --recurse-submodules` stopped to show that issue like you specified.

Basically you need to check if this sha exists. Check who pushed that commit which refers missing submodule sha. It also could be erased with forced submodule branch update.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just simply copy the content of .git/modules from another worktree to another worktree (if you don't have worktree you have to manually reconstruct it)
Then run `git submodule init && git submodule update`, and call `git pull` on the branch and git will repair itself.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I enabled `submodule.recurse` in my git config and then ran into this issue where I could not switch to that branch. In the end I did `git switch --recurse-submodules=false main` followed by `git submodule update --init --recursive` that pulled the relevant changes.